# Procedure Send Mail Alert

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I have a procedure which sends emails and this procedure is being called from other functions and procedures (primarily used for sending alerts and notifications).

One issue I face is if our mail server is down, then calling function or procedure stops execution, I mean they do not do any functionality which they are supposed to do. How can I make sure that calling function or procedure or for that matter any client which calls
MailProcedure should do its functionality even when mail server is down.

How can I achieve this? 
Any help is highly appreciable.

Mail Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MailProcedure(frm_id IN VARCHAR2, to_id IN VARCHAR2, subject IN VARCHAR2, body_text IN VARCHAR2)
AS
c utl_tcp.connection;
rc integer;
BEGIN
 c := utl_tcp.open_connection('email_server', 25);  
 rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'string'); 
 rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'from address'); 
 rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'to address');  
 rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'Subject'); 
 rc := utl_tcp.write_line(c, 'body');  
 utl_tcp.close_connection(c); 
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        null;
END;
/
```

Comment: If the mail server is down, what do you want to happen?  Do you want the caller to succeed and for no email to be sent?  Do you want the email to be queued for later delivery?  Something else?  If `MailProcedure` really has a `WHEN OTHERS THEN null` exception handler, how does it cause the caller to fail?  As written, `MailProcedure` will simply fail silently which probably isn't the best solution but certainly shouldn't cause an exception to be thrown to the caller.

Comment: If mail server is down no mail to be sent and would like to be queued for later delivery. How  can I do this?. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to queue the email for later delivery, the simplest option is to send all email messages asynchronously.  Your other procedures would call a `QueueMail` procedure that inserts a row into the new `mail_queue` table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE QueueMail(p_from IN VARCHAR2, 
                                      p_to IN VARCHAR2, 
                                      p_subject IN VARCHAR2, 
                                      p_body IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO mail_queue( mail_queue_id. from, to, subject, body )
    VALUES( mail_queue_seq.nextval, p_from, p_to, p_subject, p_body );
END;
```

You would then have a separate procedure that runs in a separate thread that actually sense the emails and removes the messages from the queue.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SendQueuedMessages
AS
BEGIN
  FOR msg IN (SELECT * FROM mail_queue )
  LOOP
    sendMessage( msg.from, msg.to, msg.subject, msg.body );
    DELETE FROM mail_queue
     WHERE mail_queue_id = msg.mail_queue_id;
    commit;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

where `sendMessage` implements the actual logic for sending an email.  I would think that you would want to use either the `utl_mail` or the `utl_smtp` package to send email rather than using `utl_tcp` but, of course, you can use `utl_tcp`.  You would then schedule the `SendQueuedMessages` procedure using either the `dbms_job` or the `dbms_scheduler` package.  Something like this

```
DECLARE
  l_jobno PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                   'BEGIN SendQueuedMessages; END;',
                   sysdate + interval '1' minute,
                   'sysdate + interval ''1'' minute' );
  commit;
END;
```

will create a job that runs the `SendQueuedMessages` procedure every minute.  If the mail server is down, the `SendQueuedMessage` procedure fails and the job is automatically rescheduled to run later.  After the first failure, the job runs again 1 minute later.  After the second failure, it runs 2 minutes later, then 4 minutes, 8 minutes, etc. until it fails 16 consecutive times.  You can choose something other than the default behavior if you want to catch the exceptions in the `SendQueuedMessages` procedure.  Since job failures cause the failure to be written to the alert log, your DBA may ask you to handle the exceptions and to handle rescheduling the job to avoid unnecessary data being written to the alert log.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your fabulous answer. I will the the job which will run the job at a specified time. Much appreciated.